# What is the proper way to update partial fields in a model without triggering the rest of validation module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Let's say I have a User model with many fields, like username, password, email, country etc. Now, I want to create a dedicated controller module for **changing password** only, but when I submit the password changing form (even this form only has two password fields), the rest of validation module in my User model will be triggered.

I think my idea is quite common, so what would be the proper way or the rails way to deal with this problem?

Comment: There should not be any problem: even if other validations are triggered, nothing has changed except the password field so they should all pass. No?

Comment: effectively you are looking for a means to apply validation for specific fields only, there are a few near duplicates of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830743/rails-perform-one-validation-only-if-all-other-validations-pass?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367508/how-to-validate-a-single-attribute-for-a-submitting-activerecord-instead-of-all